# Several insert to DB via EF6

Tags: entity-framework

I am currently working on an Application using MVC & EF.
When a user is logged in, its userid is stored in a cookie.

We retrieve this value from the Base controller accessed from other controllers.

Any save to db, we build the model, passed through EF SaveChanges.

Currently we are having an issue, when lots of users are accessing the site and saving data at the same time.

The userid is being wrongly saved. It is mismatching the data.

```
    public static void Add(Test test)
    {
        dbContext= new dbEntities();
        dbContext.Test.Add(test);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Can someone please advise if the EF is causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably your context is a single instance and is shared between requests

Comment: Yes it is. Is this an issue?

Comment: Yes, you should create new context's instance for each request

Answer (score 0):

So you mean I have to make all my calls to async?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use async await

```
public static async Task Add(Test test)
{
    dbContext = new dbEntities();
    dbContext.Test.Add(test);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Call method Add like this

```
Add(test).Wait();
```

or

```
await Add(test);
```

Comment: `Add()` isn't an asynchronous method and changing `SaveChanges()` to `SaveChangesAsync()` is not going to change the behavior of the call, why would this help?